# Reverting a bitwise/binary number to an array of values?

Tags: php

I have a a list of data that has a value attached to it that constantly gets doubled as it goes up:

```
0   = value 0
1   = value 1
2   = value 2
4   = value 3
8   = value 4
16  = value 5
32  = value 6
64  = value 7
128 = value 8
256 = value 9
512 = value 10
```

I have also been given the number x

say x = 76.

Visually, I can see that value 7 (64), value 4 (8), and value 3 (4) all sum up to 76.

What I need to be able to do, is take x, run it through a function, and return an array of the values.

I've tried looping through all the numbers in reverse and taking off what value has been used, but i got confused with lots of if statements.

Is there a built in PHP function to do this? Or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: This is called `binary`.

Comment: looks like =2^(value-1)

Comment: The first value does not get doubled though; it is also useless to use as a part of a sum.

Comment: 0 may still be returned, but I can program in for it to not put anything if 0 is returned, so I could do a if >=1 do function ect;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are looking for this-

```
function getArray($x){
    $ar = array();
    for($i = 0 ; $i < 16; $i++){
        if( ($x&(1<<$i)) != 0 ){

            array_push($ar, (1<<$i));

            // if you need positions; you should use it instead of above line
            //array_push($ar, ($i+1));

        }
    }
    return $ar;
}

print_r( getArray(76) );
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 64  
)
```

The alternate output will be (if you use `array_push($ar, ($i+1));`)-

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 7
)
```

**Explanation:**

In binary `76` presents `00000000 01001100` in 16 bit. I ran a loop from Least Significant Bit (LSB) to Most Significant Bit (MSB) (0-16). In each loop, I'm generating a new number which contains only `i'th` bit as `1` and rest of the bits are `0`. To generate it I used shifting operator `(1 << i)` which is actually 2^i. Now I did a bit wise `AND` operation between `x` and the new number. If this operation returns any nonzero number that means `i'th` bit of `x` is 1 and I'm pushing that position/value inside the array. Finally I'm returning that arry.